# Failed to execute stored procedure from the JDBC code using mysql connection

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have one database. I executed a stored procedure on it. I wrote some JDBC code to connect to this database. When I am calling this stored procedure from my JDBC code it is throwing  SQLException.

One interesting thing I found is that I have one user other than root user. This user has all the privileges to this database where the stored procedure is present.

When I use the root user I am able to call the stored procedure successfully. But with the other user I am getting SQLexception. I am not able to find why it happens like this.

For sure I want this user(other than root) has to call this stored procedure successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should provide the whole exception stacktrace, and the stored procedur.

Comment: Are you sure the user has execute proceure rights? If not try GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.myproc TO 'someuser'@'somehost';

Comment: I'd recommend adding JDBC to your tags, I recall having trouble calling sprocs from my JDBC code before too, that's all i remember though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user should have `SELECT` permissions to the `mysql.proc` and `mysql.procs_priv`.

I don't know if there exists any other solution.